# firestore iterator on querysnapshot

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm looking a right way to iterate in firestore docs;

```
        this.globalCounters = firebase.firestore().collection('AnswersCounters').doc('Questions')
```

[image]

I found a way to do this with Object.keys() but I don't think this way is the right one.

```
        this.unsubscribe_globalCounters = this.globalCounters.onSnapshot(this.showAnswers) 


 showAnswers(querySnapshot){

    let snapshotData = querySnapshot.data();
    let answersCounters =[]
    Object.keys(snapshotData).map((i)=>{

        answersCounters.push({key:i,count:snapshotData[i]})

        })
}
```

Comment: It looks a bit chaotic and non-idiomatic, but should run. What's the problem?

Comment: it run, but I'm looking another way without Object.keys()

Comment: That'd be `for (var key in snapshotData) {`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object